# Searchbar Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Consegui implementar o [`searchbar`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#searchbar) conforme documentação do `IONIC 2`.

O problema é que estou trazendo informações de um banco de dados remoto e não consigo implementar esses dados do banco na `searchbar`. É uma questão de passar a variável `array` pra dentro da função `initializeItems()`, só que não consigo.

Já tentei colocar `initializeItems(){this.item[]}`, mas daí o valor é nulo, segue abaixo os códigos que tenho:

TYPESCRIPT

```
export class ListaPage {
  items:any[];
  searchQuery: string = '';
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public service:ServiceProvider) {
    this.getDados();
    this.navCtrl=navCtrl;
    this.initializeItems();
  }
  getDados(){
    this.service.getData().subscribe(
      data =>this.items=data,
      err =>console.log(err)
    );
  }
  chamaProd(pr){
    this.navCtrl.push(ProdutoPage, {id: pr});
  }
  initializeItems() {
    this.items = ['aqui','que','quero','chamar','os dados','do banco'];
  }
  getItems(ev: any) {  
     this.initializeItems();
     let val = ev.target.value;
     if (val && val.trim() != '') {
       this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
         return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
       })
     }
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div  *ngFor="let item of items">
       {{item.nome}}
</div>
```

Comment: Tenta trocar isso initializeItems(){this.item[]} por isso initializeItems(){this.item}

Comment: @RobertoFagundes, tentei mas nao foi, so funciona com array ['aqui','que','quero','chamar','os dados','do banco'], quando passei o parametro this.item; ele retorna um erro item.toLowerCase is not a function